# Will select() block if called while there is still data to be read?

Tags: linux, sockets, select, network-programming

If a socket has data to be read and the select() function is called, will select():

1. Return immediately, indicating the socket is ready for reading, or
2. Block until more data is received on the socket

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can easily be tested, but I assure you select() will never block if there is data already available to read on one of the readfds. If it did block in that case, it wouldn't be very useful for programming with non-blocking I/O. Take the example where you are looping on select(), you see that there is data to be read, and you read it. Then while you are processing the data read, more data comes in. When you return to select() it blocks, waiting for more data. However your peer on the other side of the connection is waiting for a response to the data already sent. Your program ends up blocking forever. You could work around it with timeouts and such, but the whole point is to make non-blocking I/O efficient.

If an fd is at EOF, select() will never block even if called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

`man 2 select` seems to answer this question pretty directly:

> select() and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking.

So at least according to the manual, it would return immediately if there is any data available.

Comment: Of course, "immediately" is still subject to whatever the scheduler decides to do on system call return - but barring context switches, it should return immediately. On a very busy system, though, it might still appear to block.

Comment: @lanzz The man page also says: "readfds will be watched to see if characters become available for reading (more precisely, to see if a read will not block; in particular, a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file)".  That makes me think it is only waiting to be triggered by new data, which might include end-of-file.

Comment: If the descriptor is at `eof`, it would _not_ block; it would return the descriptor as readable, and a read would return 0 bytes without blocking, which is still consistent with the above `man` snippet ("ready" == "operation would not block").